# Errors with core types when compiling a solution using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, roslyn

I am trying to compile a solution with several C# projects targeting .NET Framework 4.6 using Roslyn (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 2.8.2 and friends).

The solution in question builds fine in VS2017, but when I try to compile through Roslyn I get loads of errors about basic core types like "The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute' could not be found".

EDIT: perhaps more importantly, there are diagnostics emitted by the MSBuildWorkspace itself once the solution is opened. They look like this:

> Msbuild failed when processing the file
>   'C:\dev\MySolution\My.Assembly.Name\My.Assembly.Name.csproj' with
>   message: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:
>   (1603, 5): The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task could not
>   be instantiated from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version
>   of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your
>   computer and that your host application is not missing a binding
>   redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type
>   'NuGet.Build.Tasks.GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask' to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:
>   (1603, 5): The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task has been
>   declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the
>   spelling of the task name and the assembly name.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var solution = await MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync(@"C:\path\to\solution.sln");
var project = solution.Products.Single(p => p.Name == "ProjectName");
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
var diagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics()
    .Where(d => !d.IsSuppressed && d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error)
    .ToArray();
foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics) { /* print */ }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Things I've tried so far:

- Adding facade DLL metadata references:

  ```
      var metadataReferenceDlls = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\", "*.dll");
      var metadataReferences = metadataReferenceDlls.Select(f => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(f)).ToArray();
      foreach (var projectId in solution.ProjectIds.ToArray())
      {
          solution = solution.AddMetadataReferences(projectId, metadataReferences);
      }
  ```
- Adding current runtime metadata references (same as above but with `Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)` as the search path). *This Works!*. However, it feels non-ideal since I still have to manually parse out all referenced DLLs.
- Installing Microsoft.Build.Locator and calling `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();` upfront

Also posted on Roslyn's GitHub here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29170

EDIT: As requested, here is the csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C768D1C6-3C45-4170-A4DB-B05B7F833181}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>My.Assembly.Name</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>My.Assembly.Name</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(SolutionDir)\StyleCop.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <GitLinkEnabled>true</GitLinkEnabled>
    <GitLinkGitRemoteUrl>http://gitlink/{revision}/{filename}</GitLinkGitRemoteUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\My.Assembly.Name.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1574, 1580, 1581, 1584, 1587, 1589, 1590, 1591, 1592, 1598, 1710, 1711, 1712, 1723</NoWarn>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RazorEngine, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\RazorEngine.3.4.2\lib\net45\RazorEngine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity.Design" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.1\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- long list of files -->
    <Compile Include="File1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="File2.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\My.OtherProject.Name\My.OtherProject.Name.csproj">
      <Project>{96b3bcc3-9052-403e-97ca-44eef392ee15}</Project>
      <Name>My.OtherProject.Name</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\StyleCop.Analyzers.1.1.0-beta007\analyzers\dotnet\cs\StyleCop.Analyzers.CodeFixes.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\StyleCop.Analyzers.1.1.0-beta007\analyzers\dotnet\cs\StyleCop.Analyzers.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\GitLink.3.1.0\build\GitLink.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you will put a .proj file. Also did you try to create compilation for you project by hand? I mean add all trees, references and put the specific options. Did this compilation have diagnostics?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria thanks for commenting. I've added an anonymized version of the csproj to the post. Also, as you've suggested I tried creating the compilation manually by adding all .cs files and metadata references. This also broke. However, I then switched from the facades directory to the directory for the current framework install and that worked!

Comment: It's well news, that it works when you add references from the framework directory. I saw that `MsBuildWorkspace` gave to you diagnostic during parse the solution. I suggest try to fix diagnostics using the same nuget version with your VS or adding a binding redirection.